# Degeneration from context switching to thrashing in the below model?

Tags: linux, context-switch

I have a component, that does the following

1. Accept a SINGLE message over network using custom protocol built over tcp/ip from source A
2. Process the message (takes roughly 500 micro second)
3. Sends the message over network to a different component, say endpoint B,  using custom protocol built over tcp/ip
4. Receives ACK from endpoint B
5. Sends ACK to source A

Rinse and repeat the above 5 steps. It is important to understand that source A will not send a second message, till it receives an ACK for previous message.

As you can see the process is idle in following cases

1. Time for source A to send one message over network to the component. Both source A and component are within same VLAN, ethernet.
2. Time for component to send processed message to endpoint B. Endpoint B is also in same VLAN connected via ethernet.
3. Time for component to receive an ACK from endpoint B.
4. Time for component to send an ACK to source A.

The above was description of the component's responsibility. From deployment perspective, i am planning to spawn say 100 of these components on a single 8 core machine. Nothing else would run on the machine. Both endpoint B and source A are on different machines, and everything is within same Ethernet.
My question is that would the above model of spawning large number of components, that spend most of their time waiting for network IO cause context thrashing ? If yes, why ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are worried. First you design an inefficient protocol then worry about how fast it will be?

Measure it, it is the only way to be sure.

I doubt that a mere 100 threads or processes will cause any problems with context switch rate.

Comment: First all components are in 1Gb Ethernet. So even though the component  waits for network IO, the over-all latency introduced due to network will be few microseconds. So the OS is going to be doing a lot of work switching process on and off the run queue.